# Actionscript ServerSocket Verify Connection

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sockets

In flash, we can create a server socket with this:

```
protected var socket:ServerSocket = new ServerSocket();
protected function createServer():void
{
    socket.bind(1234,"0.0.0.0");
    socket.addEventListener(ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, clientConnectedHandler);
    // start listening for connections
    socket.listen();
}
```

With this, any flash application try to connect to the server socket with the port 1234 will get connected. How can I do verification on connection to make sure it is connected from my application before accepting the connection on server socket?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SockerServer instance will throw errors on failure:

> RangeError — This error occurs when localPort is less than 0 or greater than 65535.
>
> ArgumentError — This error occurs when localAddress is not a
>   syntactically well-formed IP address.   IOError — when the socket
>   cannot be bound, such as when: the underlying network socket (IP and
>   port) is already in bound by another object or process. the
>   application is running under a user account that does not have the
>   privileges necessary to bind to the port. Privilege issues typically
>   occur when attempting to bind to well known ports (localPort < 1024)
>   this ServerSocket object is already bound. (Call close() before
>   binding to a different socket.) when localAddress is not a valid local
>   address.

You can use try..catch statements to handle those errors.
If those errors aren't thrown, opening port went successfully :)